# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message
>   'Syntax Error in template
>   "/data/3/1/80/27/1895679/user/2062193/htdocs/storetest/modules/blockbestsellers/blockbestsellers.tpl"
>   on line 29 "<h4><a
>   href="{$link->getPageLink('best-sales.php')}">{l
>   s='Top sellers' mod='blockbestsellers'}</a></h4>" unknown
>   tag "l"' in
>   /data/3/1/80/27/1895679/user/2062193/htdocs/storetest/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:431
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /data/3/1/80/27/1895679/user/2062193/htdocs/storetest/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(253):
>   Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->trigger_template_error('unknown
>   tag "l"', 29) #1
>   /data/3/1/80/27/1895679/user/2062193/htdocs/storetest/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php(2319):
>   Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->compileTag('l', Array) #2
>   /data/3/1/80/27/1895679/user/2062193/htdocs/storetest/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php(2812):
>   Smarty_ in
>   /data/3/1/80/27/1895679/user/2062193/htdocs/storetest/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
>   on line 431

I'm made 1.4.6.1 module, to receive a credit card pay, but i put some php includes(in "smarty" way) but that error show, im delete my changes, but error don't dissapear and many modules not show.  where is my problem, if i deleted my changes! :O

Comment: Happens to everybody, however: To be smarty about this: The code in which this error occurs would be nice to look at....

Comment: I think its Smarty cache. Just clean it.

Comment: that module: blockbestseller was not edited, and my code i deleted the changes but the problem remains...

Comment: i just deleted the content of /smarty/cache and /smarty/compile and error its the same

Comment: Thanks @AlekseyKrivtsov i just re-upload it(the module) and its works . And again thanks!